# How should I load file on s3 using Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I installed spark via `pip install pyspark`

I'm using following code to create a dataframe from a file on s3.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/home/ubuntu/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.11.335.jar:/home/ubuntu/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.8.4.jar') \
            .appName("cluster").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.load('s3a://bucket/path/to/file')
```

However I got an error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df = spark.read.load('s3a://bucket/path/to/file')
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/audience/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py
>   in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
>       164         self.options(**options)
>       165         if isinstance(path, basestring):
>   --> 166             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
>       167         elif path is not None:
>       168             if type(path) != list:
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/audience/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1158         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1159         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1160             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1161     1162         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/audience/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py
>   in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/audience/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       318                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       319                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 320                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       321             else:
>       322                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o220.load. :
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.StorageStatistics    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 28 more

If I change `s3a` to `s3` or `s3n`, it will ask for the aws access key. However, I already give the ec2 instance `AmazonS3FullAccess` in IAM.

> IllegalArgumentException: 'AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key
>   must be specified by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId and
>   fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need a way to expose your AWS credentials to the script.

The example below using botocore may be over reaching but saves you from needing to roll your own AWS config or credential parser.

First,

> **pip install botocore**

Then create a session and blindly resolve your credentials. The order for the credential resolution is [documented here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/1.7.26/docs/source/guide/configuration.rst#configuring-credentials)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import botocore.session

session = botocore.session.get_session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(
        'spark.driver.extraClassPath', 
        '/home/ubuntu/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.11.335.jar:'
        '/home/ubuntu/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.8.4.jar')
    .config('fs.s3a.access.key', credentials.access_key)
    .config('fs.s3a.secret.key', credentials.secret_key)
    .appName("cluster")
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = spark.read.load('s3a://bucket/path/to/file')
```

**EDIT**

When using s3n filesystem client, the [authentication properties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authentication_properties) are like so

```
.config('fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId', credentials.access_key)
.config('fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey', credentials.secret_key)
```

Comment: It didn't work. I still got the same error 'An error occurred while calling o570.load.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics'. If I change `s3a` to `s3n`, I got ' org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied'. I'm sure my IAM is correct, because I can access s3 buckets via `boto3`

Answer (score 1):

The first error tells you that Spark tries to load class `org.apache.hadoop.fs.StorageStatistics`. Could you ensure that your Spark version fits to  your Hadoop JAR ? Normally the class Spark tries to load was added in this commit https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/687233f20d24c29041929dd0a99d963cec54b6df#diff-114b1833bd381e88382ade201dc692e8 and regarding the release tags, released first in 3.0.0. Since you use Hadoop 2.8.4, upgrading it to 3.0.0 may be a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using Hadoop or not, because I installed Spark via `pipy`. I think I might be using standalone Spark. The spark version is 2.3. I tried `hadoop-aws-3.1.0` which gave me the same error.

Comment: its 100% critical that the version of hadoop-aws matches the hadoop-common JAR on the spark classpath, otherwise a stack traces is effectively guaranteed. And no, don't try hadoop 3.x and spark, not yet

Comment: Hi @SteveLoughran, I think I'm not using hadoop at all. My spark was installed via `pip install pyspark`, I tried `hadoop-aws` `2.73`, `2.84`, `3.1`, none of them worked. I always got the same error 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics'

Comment: Spark uses the hadoop s3 connectors to talk to S3. therefore you are using hadoop. you have classpath problems you are going to have to identify and fix yourself.